# in vs code, how to turn off auto closing bracket/quote

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code editor, if I select a word, then type a `character`, the selection will be replaced by the new character. *This is what I want*. But if I select a word, then type an open bracket/quote `("(", "[" or "{", ', ")`, the selection will be kept and the closing bracket/quote will be inserted at the end of the selection automatically.

Is there a setting to turn this off? (I've already turned off the "Auto Closing Brackets" setting)

Comment: ^What you're looking for is `"editor.autoSurround": "never"` from the second answer there.

Comment: this is the correct answer, thanks